# is there a way to search for deeply nested json in activerecord with postgres?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

Suppose I have a foos table that has a json column called "json_col"...

Is there a way with ActiveRecord to do:

```
Foo.create!(:json_col => { :foo => { :bar => 'baz' } }.to_json)

Foo.where_with_magical_json_finder(:bar => 'baz')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres 9.3, ActiveRecord 4

```
Foo.where("json_col -> 'foo' ->> 'bar' ILIKE ?", "%baz%")
```

This assumes a case-insensitive search with any sequence around 'baz'.  Your [pattern](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) may vary.

To get the 'where_with_magical_json_finder(:bar => 'baz')' method, create a scope in your Foo model.

```
scope :magic, -> { where("json_col -> 'foo' ->> 'bar' ILIKE ?", "%baz") }
```

Then call `Foo.magic`